# boost::mp11::mp_list can't define proper transition table for FSM based on boost::msm, what is missing?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm, boost-mp11

Does `boost::mp11::mp_list` can be used instead of `boost::mpl::vector` as transition-list in state-machines constructed with `boost::msm`?

I just tried it ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/aGvabM36x)) and it seems that:

1. it compiles
2. but it does not work - transitions tables are missing
3. and produces 1/3 code comparing to `boost::mpl::vector`.

I also tried `boost::fusion::vector` and it works.

What I did:

I simplified the example from `boost::msm` - [see](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/examples/MsmSimple.cpp) - just to have 2 states and 2 transitions.

I replaced all `mpl::vector` with `TypeList` defined as:

```
#ifdef USE_FUSION

#include <boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>

template <typename ...T>
using TypeList = boost::fusion::vector<T...>;

#elif USE_MP11

#include <boost/mp11/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11/mpl.hpp>


template <typename ...T>
using TypeList = boost::mp11::mp_list<T...>;

#else

template <typename ...T>
using TypeList = boost::mpl::vector<T...>;

#endif
```

The state machine is as follows:

```
namespace msm = boost::msm;

namespace test_fsm // Concrete FSM implementation
{
// events
struct play {};
struct stop {};

// Concrete FSM implementation 
struct player_ : public msm::front::state_machine_def<player_>
{
    // no need for exception handling or message queue
    typedef int no_exception_thrown;
    typedef int no_message_queue;

    // The list of FSM states
    struct Empty : public msm::front::state<> 
    {
        // optional entry/exit methods
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_entry(Event const&,FSM& ) { std::cout << "entering: Empty" << std::endl; }
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_exit(Event const&,FSM& ) { std::cout << "leaving: Empty" << std::endl; }
    };

    struct Playing : public msm::front::state<>
    {
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_entry(Event const&,FSM& ) { std::cout << "entering: Playing" << std::endl; }
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_exit(Event const&,FSM& ) { std::cout << "leaving: Playing" << std::endl; }
    };

    // the initial state of the player SM. Must be defined
    typedef Empty initial_state;
    // transition actions
    void playing(play const&)  {  }
    void stop_playing(stop const&)  {  }
    
    // guard conditions

    typedef player_ p; // makes transition table cleaner

    // Transition table for player
    struct transition_table : TypeList<
        //    Start     Event         Next      Action                 Guard
        //    +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
            _row < Empty , play        , Playing       >,
            _row < Playing , stop        , Empty       >
    > {};

    // Replaces the default no-transition response.
    template <class FSM,class Event>
    void no_transition(Event const& e, FSM&,int state)
    {
        std::cout << "no transition from state " << state
            << " on event " << typeid(e).name() << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef msm::back::state_machine<player_> player;

//
// Testing utilities.
//
static char const* const state_names[] = { "Empty", "Playing" };

void pstate(player const& p)
{
    std::cout << " -> " << state_names[p.current_state()[0]] << std::endl;
}

}
```

For this simple scenario:

```
test_fsm::player p2;
p2.start();
p2.process_event(test_fsm::play());
p2.process_event(test_fsm::stop()); 
return 0;
```

The example based on `boost::mpl::vector` (and `boost::fusion::vector` and `boost::mpl::list`) produces the output as expected:

```
entering: Empty 
leaving: Empty 
entering: Playing 
leaving: Playing
entering: Empty
```

while using of `boost::mp11::mp_list` outputs this:

```
entering: Empty
no transition from state 0 on event N8test_fsm4playE
no transition from state 0 on event N8test_fsm4stopE
```

Do you know what is missing to use `boost::mp11` or that it is currently impossible to use `boost::mp11::mp_list` as transition tables for `boost::msm` states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way to use `boost::mp11::mp_list` as a list of transition rows in `boost::msm` is to use typedef (using) - inheritance does not work; required changes are as [follows](https://godbolt.org/z/jTEnxPMTj):

```
    // Transition table for player
    using transition_table = boost::mp11::mp_list<
            _row < Empty , play        , Playing       >,
            _row < Playing , stop        , Empty       >
    >;
```

Next observation is that this version, with type-alias, works also for other types: `boost::mpl::vector`, `boost::fusion::vector`.

I guess, using of inheritance in all `boost::msm` examples (instead of type-alias) for defining transition tables, is probably reasoned by shortening template instantiations names length (not sure that).

Well, anyway, I reported it as `boost::mp11` [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/531).